# function is inaccessible (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on some code to understand some design patterns. I'm working on C# and on C++ to better understand both languages. The following code gives the error that Duck::fly() and Duck::quack() is not accessible. Could anyone help me with this error?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Object Oriented Pattern:\n\n";

    MallardDuck Duck1;
    Duck1.fly();
    Duck1.quack();

    RubberDuck Duck2;
    Duck2.fly();
    Duck2.quack();

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
};

class IFlyBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void fly();
};

class IQuackBehavior
{
public:
    virtual void quack();
};

class Duck
{
protected:
    IFlyBehavior FlyBehavior;
    IQuackBehavior QuackBehavior;

public:
    void fly()
    {
        FlyBehavior.fly();
    }
    void quack()
    {
        QuackBehavior.quack();
    }
};

class RubberDuck : Duck
{
public:
    RubberDuck() : Duck()
    {
        NoFly FlyBehavior;
        Squeak QuackBehavior;
    }
};

class MallardDuck : Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck() : Duck()
    {
        FlyWithWings FlyBehavior;
        Quack QuackBehavior;
    }
    ~MallardDuck() { };
};

class FlyWithWings : IFlyBehavior
{
    void fly()
    {
        cout << "Flapping wings.";
    }
};

class NoFly : IFlyBehavior
{
    void fly()
    {
        cout << "Can't fly.";
    }
};

class Quack : IQuackBehavior
{
    void quack()
    {
        cout << "Quack!";
    }
};

class Squeak : IQuackBehavior 
{
    void quack()
    {
        cout << "Squeak!";
    }
};
```

I have no idea why this is inaccessible since the function in duck is declared as public.

By the way: is there a way to copy the code into a code block? I had to put all spaces in front of everything now. So is there an easier way to do this?

Kind regards,

Bob

Comment: [this code produces a different error](https://ideone.com/gbR8X5)

Comment: I see that, but `FlyBehavior.fly();` is not.

Comment: Don't make the mistake of thinking that C# and C++ behave the same even for constructs that *look* the same. The semantics of many things are different between the languages even when the syntax looks identical.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve] and provide actual error message

Comment: You can copy code into a code block by pasting it normally, selecting it all, and hitting the `{}` button in the toolbar or Ctrl+K. That will automatically add four spaces to the start of each line.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest code that reproduces your problem that I've managed to come up with is:

```
// main.cpp
class A
{
public:
    void foo() { };
};

class B : A
{
};

int main()
{
    B a;
    a.foo();
}
```

It clearly does not compile:

```
$gcc main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:12: error: ‘void A::foo()’ is inaccessible within this context
      a.foo();
            ^
main.cpp:5:11: note: declared here
      void foo() { };
           ^~~
main.cpp:15:12: error: ‘A’ is not an accessible base of ‘B’
      a.foo();
            ^
```

But when you change the

```
 class B : A
```

to the

```
 class B : public A
```

it will compile just fine.

If you define your type with the use of the `class` keyword the private access is implicit. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class

> If access-specifier is omitted, it defaults to public for classes
>   declared with class-key struct and to private for classes declared
>   with class-key class.

So you triggered the "private inheritance" - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Private_inheritance.

> When a class uses private member access specifier to derive from a
>   base, all public and protected members of the base class are
>   accessible as private members of the derived class (private members of
>   the base are never accessible unless friended).

Comment: Thank you very much. Totally missed that one. However, now that i'm able to compile, i get the following error messages:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall IFlyBehavior::fly(void)" 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall IQuackBehavior::quack(void)"

Comment: You decleard the `IFlyBehavior::fly()` and `IQuackBehavior::quack()` functions but you never defined them. If you intended those two classes to be the abstract ones you should put the ` = 0;` instead of `;` after the definition. The code won't start to compile, you have to fix a few other things if you want to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

(1) Non-pure virtual function:

```
virtual void fly();
```

(2) [Default access](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.access#3) of classes are private.

```
class IFlyBehavior
```

With that, to address (1), I believe interfaces in OOP context are abstract classes where you need to **implement** it.

For (1), you need to declare the function as [pure virtual](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.abstract#2) to make the `class IFlyBehavior` as an [abstract class](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.abstract).

```
class IFlyBehavior {
   virtual void fly() = 0; // pure virtual function
                           // making IFlyBehavior as abstract class
};
```

For (2), you can have your concrete class `Duck` implementing `IFlyBehavior` as struct to have a **public** default access.

```
struct Duck: IFlyBehavior { // Let the whole world know that ducks fly
    inline void fly() { // define how ducks fly
        std::cout << "can fly in v-formation" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your aproach but now i'm getting a different error. Could you tell me what is wrong with what i'm doing?
The error message is: E0322, Object of abstract class type 'IFlyBehavior' is not allowed. The same goes for the IQuackBehavior. The error is in the duck class where i create the objects. 
How would i go about making this work properly?

Btw, i didn't use a struct since if i would do it your way wouldn't that beat the purpose of having a different class so that not all duck types can fly?